# Python PyCharm not finding module common

Tags: python, import, anaconda

I'm using python 2.7.10 through Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit) with opencv 2.4.11 on windows. I ran the opencv sample watershed.py in the command line by typing "python watershed.py" and it works just fine.

Strangely (or maybe not?), when I run the same code in the PyCharm (community edition 4.5.2), it does not run and throws an error: "ImportError: cannot import name Sketcher". Note that I've been developing in PyCharm for a while and everything else seems to work fine (although admittedly I don't use that many different imported modules). I've cross-checked to make sure that I don't have multiple Python installs. I don't. I only have Anaconda, and only one install of that. Any ideas?? Thanks.

UncleMeh

Comment: You do not have any virtual envs set up for Anaconda?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Sketcher package has not been installed with the python version you are using in your IDE.Once you install it on the IDE the sketcher package would be available for you to work. Hope it helps.